# c# How to obtain the nth object property name in a dynamic object

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to enumerate the NAMES of properties of JSON deserialised object.

```
dynamic x = data.elements[i];

Console.Write(x);

{{
  "order_type": "request",
  "order_id": "A511",
  "order_Date" : null,
  "order_name": "Preston",
}}
```

.GetProperties() will return the following:

```
Console.Write(x.GetType().GetProperties())

    [0]: {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenType Type}
    [1]: {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken Item [System.Object]}
    [2]: {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken Item [System.String]}
    [3]: {Boolean HasValues}
    [4]: {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken First}
    [5]: {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken Last}
    [6]: {Int32 Count}
    [7]: {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer Parent}
    [8]: {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken Root}
    [9]: {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken Next}
    [10]: {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken Previous}
    [11]: {System.String Path}
```

It has "`First`", and "`Last`".  It has "`Next`" and "`Previous`".  It even has "`Parent`".

But I need the name of the "nth" property.  For instance, I need a reference to "order_date" in order to get it's name.

The goal here is to replace the null with empty string "".  But I need a way of determining the name of the property that has that null.

If I am going about this completely wrong, and there is a better way to do this, I am open to correction.

Comment: Do you _need_ to use `dynamic` here, or can you treat the object as a `JObject`?

Comment: I could treat it as a JObject.  But what do I do with  it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the Where as Charlie's comment mentions, but if you need to iterate properties, this is one way.

```
public void DoWork()
        {
            string jsonString = @"
{
""order_type"": ""request"",
""order_id"": ""A511"",
""order_Date"" : null,
""order_name"": ""Preston"",
}
";
            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> pair in jObject)
            {
                string keyName = pair.Key;
                Console.WriteLine(keyName);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For openers, I did figure out this:

```
TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(data.elements[i])[2].Name; // --> "order_date"
```

So, now I can for() each one and check for nulls.

Open to other/better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use LINQ on the `Properties`

```cs
x.Properties.Where(j => j.Type == JTokenType.Null)
```